# How can I create WPF User Control as dll and then see it in another WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I created WPF User Control Library template but I don't know how to create dll and use it in another WPF application.

Comment: Hope this article will help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, Click
File -> New -> Visual C# -> Class Library 
 to create add dll project.

Then, Right click the project and add WPF usercontrol. Later build it and add the dll as reference to your WPF project and use it.

Comment: Thank you. I did that, but I can't see my control in new wpf application. I added the reverence, but no my control in toolbox.

Comment: Import usercontrol namespace  and add the usercontrol whereever you want in in xaml. 
Refer : [How to: Import a Namespace into XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: In case you could not add userControl in a "class library" project, use the project template "WPF User Control Library" to create project instead of "class library". Otherwise you need to self config the assembly info